# OSX Anaconda Python 2 Kivy Android Buildozer Command failed

Tags: android, python, anaconda, kivy, conda

While trying to just run the example program on my Android phone, I got this error while running `buildozer android debug deploy run`.

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /Users/USER/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /Users/USER/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /Users/USER/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Command failed: /Users/USER/miniconda3/envs/Kivy2New/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/Users/USER/Desktop/TestKivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

All with after just installing Kivy, Cython 0.19 and running `buildozer init`.
The full log with level 2 [here](https://pastebin.com/ZeDnP7W7).

I am running Anaconda on OSX with Python 2 (But same error occurs when on Python 3).

Thanks!

Comment: Edit `buildozer.spec` and replace `log_level = 1` with `log_level = 2`. Retry `buildozer android debug`

Comment: @ikolim I see, I previously tried just adding `log_level = 2` at the top, and nothing changed. I will try this and update the question.

Comment: @ikolim I added the new log.